# @ngrx Angular @ngrx/store-devtools instrumentOnlyWithExtension

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

Add @ngrx/store and try to add StoreDevtool extensions

```
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrumentOnlyWithExtension({
  maxAge: 5
})
```

and get error

> Property 'instrumentOnlyWithExtension' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   StoreDevtoolsModule'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

already found the answer, on the latest version this property was replaced with `instrument`

```
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
  maxAge: 5
})
```